# "Launch Dropbox–Website" opens in my editor instead of the browser

Tags: dropbox, mime-type

When I use the *"Dropbox–Website starten"* entry from the Dropbox App menu (I guess this would be *"Launch Dropbox–Website"* in English), a file is generated at `/tmp/….html` and opened in my editor (Sublime) instead of the browser.

How do I fix this, so that it will open in my browser instead?